# Active record, undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I am getting undefined method error in my rails console if I try to get something from model `SubQuantity` 
I have a model called `Subquantity`, right now in my model I have
 
`SubQuantity.rb` 
`belongs_to :product` 
`belongs_to :cart`
`end` 
and I have an integer defined in `SubQuantity` model called `sub_quantity`. In my code I am trying to do something like this 
`subq = SubQuantity.where(product_id:@product.id, cart_id:current_user.cart.id)` 
in return I am getting this, 
`[#<SubQuantity:0x007fbbdc046d08`
  `id: 4,`
  `sub_quantity: 1,`
  `product_id: 4,`
  `cart_id: 6,`
  `created_at: Sun, 22 May 2016 11:03:55 UTC +00:00,`
  `updated_at: Sun, 22 May 2016 11:03:55 UTC +00:00>]`
and whenever I try to do something like this, 
`subq.sub_quantity` 
I am getting this error, 
`NoMethodError: undefined method sub_quantity for`
 
`#<SubQuantity::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fbbdc04d838>`.
This is not only with sub_quantity, I am getting exact errors for every thing in subq even with subq.id.
What is wrong here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you use **`where`** method, it returns an array even if the result is **one** object. To fix your problem you must call `.first`, to extract the first result from the array (in this case is the only one). Example:

```
subq = SubQuantity.where(product_id: @product.id, cart_id: current_user.cart.id)
subq.first.sub_quantity
```

Another way, without `first` would be to use `find_by`. It works just like `where`method but returns exactly one result, the first one it can find.

```
subq = SubQuantity.find_by(product_id: @product.id, cart_id: current_user.cart.id)
subq.sub_quantity
```